# Python: Sorting Football Stats

Tags: python, sorting, statistics

To get right to my point, my goal is to take 5 files (5 seasons of football) and add each players stats up to make an all time leaders list, i.e. passing, rushing, receiving.

Each player may not have played in each season so I can't seem to find a way to enumerate through every file, adding the stats if the player is found, or just printing that line if not. I found that 3 files have the columns (yds, td, fum) a certain way and 2 of them have it the almost opposite.

Without trying to do this in an unpythonic like 300 lines, should I combine the two that are different and rearrange them?

I guess I want the ability to pass any number of files and get out stats leaders. Only problem is, I would have to make a program for each category?

I'm definitely not new to programming, but I am fairly new to python so any help would be much appreciated!!

```
lines4 = [re.split("\s+", line4) for line4 in file4]
lines5 = file5.readlines()
for i,line4 in enumerate(lines4):
    name = line4[0:-7]
    name = " ".join(name)
    name = re.split(",", name)
    name = name[0]
    str(name)
    stats4 = line4[-6:-1]

    if re.search(r"^%s"%name, lines5[i]):
        line5 = re.split(r"\s+", lines5[i])
        stats5 = line5[-6:-1]
        yds = float(stats4[0]) + float(stats5[0])
        td = int(stats4[1]) + float(stats5[1])
        car = int(stats4[2]) + float(stats5[2])
        fmb = int(stats4[3]) + float(stats5[3])
        avg = float(stats4[4]) + float(stats5[4])

    else:
        yds = float(stats4[0])
        td = int(stats4[1])
        car = int(stats4[2])
        fmb = int(stats4[3])
        avg = float(stats4[4])

    if len(str(name)) < 8:
        newline = str(name) + "\t\t\t\t" + str(yds) + "\t\t" + str(td) + "\t\t" + str(car) + "\t\t" + str(fmb) + "\t\t" + str(avg) + "\n"
    elif len(str(name)) > 14:
        newline = str(name) + "\t\t\t" + str(yds) + "\t\t" + str(td) + "\t\t" + str(car) + "\t\t" + str(fmb) + "\t\t" + str(avg) + "\n"
    else:
        newline = str(name) + "\t\t\t" + str(yds) + "\t\t" + str(td) + "\t\t" + str(car) + "\t\t" + str(fmb) + "\t\t" + str(avg) + "\n"
    filettl.write(newline)

file4.close()
file5.close()
filettl.close()
```

Sample Input:
**file4**
49erswag,null   New York Jets   14  0   3   0   4.7
A Beast Playa,null  New England Patriots    23  0   7   0   3.3
A Swanky Guy 2,null San Diego Chargers  154 1   29  2   5.3
ACIDRUST,null   New York Jets   4   0   1   0   4
Aj dahitman,null    Atlanta Falcons 1898    19  227 2   8.4
Aldizzl,R   New Orleans Saints  45  0   10  0   4.5
Areis21,O   Dallas Cowboys  58  0   13  2   4.5
at43,null   New York Jets   214 1   48  1   4.5
Ayala2012xTCU,null  New York Giants 195 0   57  1   3.4
B O R Nx 25,Rookie  Philadelphia Eagles 31  0   13  1   2.4

**file5**
a toxic taz,ECU Baltimore Ravens    307 4   44      7
AbNL Boss,R Miami  Dolphins 509 4   174 2   2.9
AFFISHAUL,  Houston Texans  190 0   35  2   5.4
AJ DA HITMAN,   Baltimore Ravens    1283   19  228 6   5.6
allen5422,null  Carolina  Panthers  112 2   18  0   6.2
Allxdayxapx,R   Miami  Dolphins 264 1   76  2   3.5
AlpHaaNike, R   San Francisco  49ers    51  1   10  1   5.1
Aura Reflexx,ECU    Houston Texans  215 1   40  0   5.4
AWAKEN DA BEAST,    Atlanta Falcons -5  0   4   1   -1.3
AxDub24,.   Miami  Dolphins -3  0   2   1   -1.5
Ayala2012xTCU,null  Pittsburgh Steelers 568 4   173 1   3.3
BALLxXHAWKXx,R  New England Patriots    221 1   47  2   4.7
BANG FIGHTY007,     New York Giants 983 6   171 3   5.7

Comment: post a small sample of your file (csv?) schema. from what I understand, you could use a default dict and append each record in form the file into a list associated with a specific player: `stats[player_name].append(stat)` where `stats = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: just updated with some sample data

Comment: Do your files have headers or separate dictionary files that define the various fields and their order?  If your data always come without a header and the order of variables can change, then the problem is harder.  If you have headers, then `csv.DictReader` is what you need.

Comment: The files do have headers. I just omitted them for consistency since some were in other orders

Comment: well, don't do that.  put the data as it is.

Comment: I've looked through csv.DictReader and am still unclear exactly how to implement it. Any examples I've found are completely irrelevant